# Visio File-type differences?

Tags: visio

Just looking to understanding what the difference is between a Visio Stencil File (.vssx) and a Visio Drawing File (.vsdx)?

I'm unsure if there will be an issue with using the file in importing the file into MS word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .vssx is a stencil document type and represents a container for master shapes that will be 'instanced' in a drawing document (.vsdx).  If you're embedding in Word then you'll be adding a drawing document.